# problem listing files from sftp

Tags: linux, ksh, sftp

I am having difficulties trying to list out files based upon file pattern with respect to files that have spaces.  Below is my terminal status.  What I want to do is get a list of files from a given folder.  In the example provided to me, there is one file, called `APP Extract.csv`.

when trying to show the list of files, I am also getting echo from the run.  I have tried `-q`, `-qq`, `>/dev/null 2>&1` to no avail.

How do I get the list of files, even when the files have spaces?

of note, This system is `AIX` and runs `KSH`

```
$ LIST=$(echo "ls *.csv" | sftp -qq -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa_client ${USER}@${HOST}:${TPATH})

$ echo $LIST
sftp> ls *.csv APP Extract.csv

$ echo $LIST[1]
sftp> ls *.csv APP Extract.csv [1]

$ for thing in $LIST; do
multi-line mode >         echo $thing
multi-line mode > done
sftp>
ls
*.csv
APP
Extract.csv
```

Comment: Hey.  thanks.  unfortunately that resulted in `This service allows sftp connections only.`

Comment: You probably know this, but: command substitution (`$(...)`) is assigning to the variable `LIST` a string composed by two lines: 1) `sftp> ls *.csv` - the echo of the remote command; 2) `APP Extract.csv` the name of the file listed remotely by `ls`. You see all in one line because `echo $LIST` splits the string and newlines and spacing are lost. Try `echo "$LIST"` instead. You can prevent `sftp` from echoing the remote command on standard output by prepending a `@` to it as in `echo "@ls *.csv`, or you can cut it out locally with `echo "$LIST" | tail -n +2`.